# Jquery tablesorter plugin - show only first x rows

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the Jquery tablesorter plugin version 2.0 and I am wondering if there is a way to first sort all the rows in my table and then only display the first 10 or x rows. i.e. I want to preserve the row ordering I have specified in my declaration but only show the user the first x rows.

Here is my table declaration. How would I change this to only show the first x rows on load after the ordering specified below has been applied?

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#olcTable").tablesorter({
        sortList: [[2,1],[5,1], [3,1]], 
        stripeRowsOnStartUp: true,
        headers: { 
            0: { sorter: false },
            1: { sorter: false },
            2: { sorter: false },           
            3: { sorter: false },
            4: { sorter: false },
            5: { sorter: false }            
        } 
    });
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [pager plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html).

Comment: FWIW that pager plugin appears to have moved here: 
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html